# SQL/PHP - Get table name in PHP from UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT entry_id,a.about,null title,null article ,null description

FROM about a 

WHERE 
(
MATCH(a.about) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
AND a.user_id='$user_id'

UNION
select entry_id,null, b.title,b.article,b.description
from articles b 

WHERE
(
MATCH(b.title,b.article,b.description) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
AND b.user_id='$user_id'
```

Is it possible to find out the origin of a result here (which table) in PHP?

So if a match comes from the articles table as opposed to the about table can that information be retrieved in PHP somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another column on the query to distinguish them.
Like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS Field0, Field1, Field2 from Table_A
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS Field0, Field1, Field2 from Table_B
```

Rows returned with the Field0 set to 1 are from table A, if it's the value 2 it's from table B

Comment: Are you saying add a column that doesn't exist, wont that cause an error?

Comment: No, has long has the column is the same datatype.
And you are not selecting a column in that union, it's just a value. I will edit the post to make it clear!

Comment: That's kind of working but it's confusing, so before AS has to be an integer? and after AS is the key? so in php $row['Field0'] would equal "1" or "2"? It would be could if it wasn't an integer.

Comment: It does not have to be an integer...
In SQL you can select any value of any datatype, of course the value you selected will repeat on each and every line of the table you are selecting from!

Comment: It's ok I just had to put the value in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use "SQL aliases"

> SQL aliases are used to give a database table, or a column in a table,
>   a temporary name.

Basically aliases are created to make column names more readable.

**SQL Alias Syntax for Columns**

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name
FROM table_name;
```

**SQL Alias Syntax for Tables**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name AS alias_name;
```

Comment: But when using union there would have a unique column name in each table, which in this example there isn't.

Comment: I should clarify there wont be once I add all the union statements (16 more)